# What is the recommended way of passing arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I show 2 modes:

- Mode A : The argument is saved previously in a variable.
- Mode B : The argument is passed directly.

Here I show 2 cases:

**Case 1:** Argument without concatenation

```
//Mode A:
const msg = this.test.fullTitle();
return helper.error(msg, err, done);

//Mode B:
return helper.error(this.test.fullTitle(), err, done);
```

**Case 2:** Argument with concatenation

```
//Mode A:
const msg = this.test.fullTitle() + ' welcome';
return helper.error(msg, err, done);

//Mode B:
return helper.error(this.test.fullTitle() + ' welcome', err, done);
```

**Question:**

Which mode is recommended, readable, efficient or is it just a personal style?

Comment: I don't think javascript supports passing by name out of the box. So there is no difference between various passing styles. Also, strings are immutable in javascript. There is no chance the error function can mutate the msg variable even if it wasn't const.

Comment: As for readability , again javascript does not allow named parameters (i.e `f(error="msg")`.  The alternative is to simply pass an object literal to the function. `f({error : "msg"})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For case 2 mode A:

```
const fullTitle = this.test.fullTitle();
const msg =  `${fullTitle} welcome`;
return helper.error(msg, err, done);
```

Points I'd like to highlight are:

1. Use es6 features like "${variableName}" instead of contacting string using "+".
2. Instead of passing a long list of arguments prefer passing a single object( on the functions that you create).

   - Any functions that you create should accept a single object. By doing that you won't have to care about the order of arguments that you have to pass in the function.

If your helper function accepts a single object as an argument then it'd look like:

```
const fullTitle= this.test.fullTitle();
const msg =  `${fullTitle} welcome`;
const err = null;
const done = () => {};
return helper.error({msg, err, done});
```

Your helper function's definition would look like following:

```
const error = (params) => {
const {msg , err , done  } = params;
//do something here
}
```

Comment: That's *too* verbose now…

Answer (score 1):

Code clarity shouldn't be all that difficult to figure out on your own. Pick a style, and look at it. Does it seem clear and readable? Are there any problems with the approach? Does writing the value inline cause the line to extend too far to the right? If so, either use a variable or put the arguments on their own line (or each one on its own line).

So basically the answer is to use common sense and just make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

**In my point of view**

i will use `Parameter without concatenation` with `mode A` because :

- we can test it using unit tests
- easy to write and to understand
- in complexes cases you can easy transfer your code to `Typescript` or other language styles

Comment: What does this have to do with TypeScript? Both modes are valid JS, and as such are also valid TS.

Comment: What exactly would you be testing in a unit test here?

Answer (score 0):

From a point of efficiency or performance, there is no difference. In both cases the function `fullTitle()` will be evaluated first and the returned string will be passed to `error()` function. Concatenation is a possible overhead (strings are immutable in JavaScript). But is probably negligible in these cases.

Now if you somehow implement lazy evaluation or a form of pass by name in your library, passing style will make a huge difference.

In my opinion, function readability is partly related to named parameters. Again, JavaScript does not support named parameters. It is impossible to do `error(message="msg")`. If this level of readability is absolutely required, one can adopt a style of passing object literals to functions.

```
error({message : "msg"});
```